# autosummary with toctree also lists imported members

Tags: python, python-sphinx, toctree

I use Sphinx and autosummary to produce the documentation of a Python software. It works well but the produced .rst files also list the imported functions and classes, which is not the behaviour I would like.

For example a package "packageex" with the docstring:

```
"""
Package Example (:mod:`packageex`)
==================================

.. currentmodule:: packageex
.. autosummary::
   :toctree:

   module0
   module1
"""
```

would produce a file packageex.module0.rst with

```
Module0 (:mod:`packageex.module0`)
=================================

.. currentmodule:: packageex.module0

.. rubric:: Functions

.. autosummary::

   f0
   f1
   f2_imported
   f3_imported

.. rubric:: Classes

.. autosummary::

   Class0
   ClassImported
```

Is there a way to list only the functions and classes defined in the module (and not those imported)?

In the doc of autodoc (http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/autodoc.html), there is "In an automodule directive with the members option set, only module members whose `__module__` attribute is equal to the module name as given to automodule will be documented. This is to prevent documentation of imported classes or functions. Set the imported-members option if you want to prevent this behaviour and document all available members. Note that attributes from imported modules will not be documented, because attribute documentation is discovered by parsing the source file of the current module." Is it possible to get the same behaviour with autosummary?

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/1061/autosummary-document-imported-functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by mzjn, it seems to be a known strange behaviour of the extension autosummary. In order to get the wanted behaviour (i.e. to prevent the listing of imported objects), I have just modified the function `get_members` (l. 166 of sphinx.ext.autosummary.generate) like so:

```
def get_members(obj, typ, include_public=[], imported=False):
    items = []
    for name in dir(obj):
        try:
            obj_name = safe_getattr(obj, name)
            documenter = get_documenter(obj_name, obj)
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        if documenter.objtype == typ:
            try:
                cond = (
                    imported or 
                    obj_name.__module__ == obj.__name__
                    )
            except AttributeError:
                cond = True
            if cond:
                items.append(name)
    public = [x for x in items
              if x in include_public or not x.startswith('_')]
    return public, items
```

Comment: noticed this problem still exists in the latest sphinx. not sure why it is not fixed with the code here. it is very regretable.

Comment: Is it still a problem? https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1061 has been closed.

Comment: Just for future reference: The code does not work for me. The .rst file produced to document my module is empty. Use with care!