# Include specific imported functions in sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Let's say that `my_module` has the following `__init__.py`:

```
from my_module.misc import f2

def f1(p1,p2):
    """
    My f1 function.

    :param p1: First parameter.
    :param p2: Second parameter.
    :return: Returned value.
    """
    return p1 + p2
```

Where the `misc.py` contains the following function:

```
def f2(p1,p2):
    """
    My f2 function.

    :param p1: First parameter.
    :param p2: Second parameter.
    :return: Returned value.
    """
    return p1 - p2
```

I am documenting `my_module` using sphinx with the following approach and `f2` is not appearing in the result, is there a way to specify that it should be included?

```
my_module
---------

.. automodule:: my_module
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
```

Comment: See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/1061 and linked issues

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/25405110/8033585 - an opposite issue may provide some hints

Comment: Ideally it would be preferable to select what members to include, like `f2` in this example, and not all that are imported.

Comment: I think it should work if you add `f2.__module__ = "my_module"` in `__init__.py`.

Comment: Another option is to add `__all__ = ["f1", "f2"]` in `__init__.py`.

Comment: The second suggestion works for me, the first now does not. Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it please?

Comment: I cannot explain why `f2.__module__ = "my_module"` does not work for you. Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47903710/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22096187/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/30856279/407651.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you add an `__all__` list in __init__.py.

```
from my_module.misc import f2

__all__ = ["f1", "f2"]

def f1(p1,p2):
    """
    My f1 function.

    :param p1: First parameter.
    :param p2: Second parameter.
    :return: Returned value.
    """
    return p1 + p2
```

From the [Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/autodoc.html#directive-automodule):

> For modules, `__all__` will be respected when looking for members unless you give the `ignore-module-all` flag option. Without `ignore-module-all`, the order of the members will also be the order in `__all__`.